# Error message harvesting in the minswap farm

Tags: error

I have liquidity pairs on app.minswap.org. I have 5 ada as collateral. I am trying to harvest rewards in the farm. I get this error message: Unexpected error value: "Not enough ADA leftover to include non-ADA assets in a change address"

I am using the nami wallet.

Not sure what I can do to remedy this issue. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem as mentioned above.
I could not withdraw or migrate from ADA-MIN Farm. Always receiving: " Failure Notice: Need additional 5000000 lovelace but only 2939420 lovelace is available to choose." I have put addionial >100 ADA in attached Nami wallet but still the same problem. No clue, what do do anymore.. any help is very welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native assets normally need to be sent along with 1 or 2 ADA ie can not be sent just on their own.

Check the MinSwap docs for minimum requirements when harvesting:

https://docs.minswap.org/yield-farming

Answer (score 0):

Any change that's left over needs to be at least 1 ADA - if the change contains native assets then it's even more.

To solve the problem, just fund your wallet with an additional 10 ADA to be save and you should be able to harvest your minswap yields.

If you wanna get into details take a look at this:
https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/minimum-ada-value-requirement

Comment: Thanks, adding 50 ADA worked. I was able to harvest.

Comment: Would appreciate if you can mark my comment as answer with the checkmark then 